# What is the best way to initialize the Variable in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

In TensorFlow, I can initialize variables in two the ways:

1. **Call `global_variable_intializer()` before declaration of variable:**

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf

   # Initialize the global variable and session
   init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
   sess = tf.Session()
   sess.run(init)

   W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
   x = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
   b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
   linear_model = W * x + b
   ```
2. **Call `global_variable_intializer()` after declaration of variable:**

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf

   W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
   x = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
   b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
   linear_model = W * x + b 

   # Initialize the global variable and session
   init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
   sess = tf.Session()
   sess.run(init)
   ```

What is the difference between both? Which is the best way to initialize variables?

**Edit**

This is the actual program I am running :

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Initialize the global variable and session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)



linear_model = W * x + b

square_delta = tf.square(linear_model - y)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(square_delta)

fixW = tf.assign(W, [-1.])
fixb = tf.assign(b, [1.])

sess.run([fixW, fixb])

print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1,2,3,4], y:[0,-1,-2,-3]}))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case 1, the variables are not initialized, and if you try

```
sess.run(linear_model)
```

it should give you some kind of error (FailedPreconditionError on my compiler).

Case 2 is the working one.

The command

```
tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

should be called after all variables are created, otherwise the same error will be raised.

As far as I understand, each time you call tf.Variable, the nodes related to a variable are added to the graph. These are the following:

```
Variable/initial_value
Variable
Variable/Assign
Variable/read
```

(you obtain the nodes constructed so far with the command

```
for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
    print n.name
```

)

The variable itself, has no value until you run within a Session the Variable/Assign node.

The command

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

creates a single node containing all the assign nodes of all the variables constructed so far, and associate it to the python variable 'init' so that when it is executed the line

```
sess.run(init)
```

all variables acquire the initial value.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between both options is that the first one doesn't work. Attempting to `sess.run(linear_model)` results in

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_3

So, somewhat unsurprisingly, you should initialize variables after creating them.

Comment: I have edit the question with the actual program. Try running it.

Comment: In your program, you added some `tf.assign` that makes a difference.

Comment: it works because you run manually assign nodes that associate a value to the variables

Answer (score 1):

You should see Tensorflow as a graph,
with:

`W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b`

you are only describing your tensorflow graph.
if you print linear_model you'll have a tensor with no value waiting the graph to run: `<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>`

Tensorflow will run you graph and "*export*" the value you want only when running a session with `my value = sess.run(linear_model)`

That's why you should consider your second solution !